# django template forloop.counter multiple operations

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to perform multiple mathematics operations on a `forloop.counter` in my Django template. Specifically I am trying to identify every 29th instance, after the 24th; so the 24th, 53rd, 82nd, 111th, 140th instances etc....

I have tried the following without success:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 24 or widthratio forloop.counter|add:"-24" 29 1 %}
{% if forloop.counter == 24 or forloop.counter|add:"-24"|divisibleby:29 %}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help me acheive my aim? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "*I am trying to perform multiple mathematics operations on a forloop.counter in my Django template.*" don't do that (!). Django template language is deliberately restricted to avoid doing complicated stuff in the templates. Such logic belongs in the *view*.

Comment: The purpose is to apply different CSS formatting to those rows in a table. Is that possible via the view?

Comment: of course, you can `zip` the condition in the iterable, and then use an `if` in the template to inspect that data. Since Python is "Turing complete", this meand that everything you can do in a template, you can definitely do in a view.

Comment: That's not really the definition of Turing-completeness @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @ubadub: no, it is a logical consequence of Turing completeness :) Otherwise it would not start with a "Since". Point is that Python is conceptually Turing complete, hence unless Oracle machines exists, it means that you can not generate any stream of content with another devide that is Turing complete (and not more powerful) that can not be generated with a view. So a consequence is that since a template is at most Turing complete, it can not produce a stream that a view can not produce.

Comment: While that's theoretically true, that doesn't mean *in practice* "everything you can do [with one Turing-complete system], you can definitely do in another [Turing-complete system]." For example, the program my thermostat is running probably Turing-complete, and so is my computer('s OS), and yet, I can't watch Netflix on my thermostat, nor can my computer adjust my air-conditioning. There are other relevant factors besides Turing-completeness.

Comment: Well nor any thermostat nor any computer or airconditioner are Turing complete :) all humans tend to be happy with a finite state machine :) Like Turing pointed out in his first AI paper, there are a lot of traps to eventually get there, and humans are - to the best of my knowledge - still stuck at the first trap. Furthermore the fact that you can watch Netflix on a device is in fact irrelevant, since Turing completeness does not deal with seeing, hearing, etc. things, but with calculating things. A webserver is for example usually not used to see things, it transforms a request in a response.

Comment: I'm well aware Turing-completeness doesn't deal with "seeing, hearing, etc. things" which is exactly my point. Views and templates, however, literally *do* deal with "seeing, hearing, etc. things."

Comment: @ubadub: no, they produce a stream that is wrapped in a HTTP response. `<b>bold</b>` does not produce boldface text, it is simply a stream. The browser does not even deal with that: it simply generates a stream of pixels that are send to the screen, and it is a screen that reads the screen buffer and produces something we humans see as text. That's is exactly the power of the Turing machine, that it basically captures a lot by making abstraction of all the "peripherals". If you read for example "*Computational Complexity*" the first chapter explains why the computational model does not matter.

Comment: In essence one can see these peripherals as "side-effects", like for example Haskell's `IO` monad also enables one to write pure functions, and at the same time talk to the screen, etc. In essence you can see a HTTP webserver as a Turing machine where initially the HTTP request is put on the tape, and at the end, the HTTP response should be put on the tape. What a device does with that is irrelevant (at least for the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like:

```
{% for element in collection %}
  {% if forloop.counter|add:"-24"|divisibleby:"29" %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

given the offset (here `24`) is smaller than the period (here `29`), this will work, otherwise we need an extra condition (for example with `31` and `29`):

```
{% for element in collection %}
  {% if forloop.counter >= 31 forloop.counter|add:"-31"|divisibleby:"29" %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For example:

```
>>> tp = '{% for element in collection %}{% if forloop.counter|add:"-24"|divisibleby:"29"%}A{% else %}B{% endif %}{% endfor %}'
>>> Template(tp).render(Context({'collection': range(100)}))
'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB'
```

as you can see, for the iterations where the condition holds, the `A` is printed.

But in case you need to write complicated logic, in general you should reconsider the design, and look if you can not "move logic" to the view instead.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I really appreciate your explanation and solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting option, besides Willem's, is to first write a modulo filter:

```
@register.filter
def modulo(num, val):
    return num % val
```

And then in your template use the filter:

```
{% if forloop.counter|modulo:29 0 %}
```

However in general you can and should do such operations in your view, not your template. It's not clear why you're going about doing it this way, so you may have your reasons, but try to avoid it if you can.